# Does there exist a tool for DB schema migration where schema are specified using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, database-migration

I am used to Django South http://south.aeracode.org/, which allows schema and data migrations for Django projects. Does there exist a similar tool for Hibernate projects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate provides its own (limited) [tools](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/toolsetguide.html#toolsetguide-s1-6) for schema migration.
There are several caveats attached to it, including a warning "not to use it for production instances", although I have not personally experienced any issues using it against a prod system.

I wouldn't advise it for data migration, or large scale relational mapping changes, but for simple changes it is generally adequate (at the very least, it can be run to generate the required DDL statements which can later be run manually).

Answer (score 1):

[LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/) does offer [Hibernate support](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/hibernate) but I don't have practical experience with it.  From the webpage:

> The LiquiBase-Hibernate  integration records the database changes required by your current Hibernate mapping to a change log file which you can then inspect and modify as needed before executing.